# Efficient loop through Java List

Tags: java, android, optimization, dalvik

The following list is from the google I/O talk in 2008 called "Dalvik Virtual Machine Internals" its a list of ways to loop over a set of objects in order from most to least efficient:

```
(1) for (int i = initializer; i >=0; i--) //hard to loop backwards
(2) int limit = calculate_limit(); for (int i= 0; i< limit; i++)
(3) Type[] array = get_array(); for (Type obj : array)
(4) for (int i =0; i< array.length; i++) //gets array.length everytime
(5) for (int i=0; i < this.var; i++) //has to calculate what this.var is
(6) for (int i=0; i < obj.size(); i++) //even worse calls function  each time
(7) Iterable list = get_list(); for (Type obj : list) //generic object based iterators slow!
```

The first 3 are in the same territory of efficiency, avoid 7 if possible. This is mainly advice to help battery life but could potentially help java SE code too.

My question is: why (7) is slow and why (3) is good? I thought it might be the difference between Array and List for (3) and (7). Also, as Dan mentioned (7) creates loads of small temporary objects which have to be GCed, I'm a bit rusty on Java nowadays, can someone explain why? It's in his [talk video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptjedOZEXPM) at 0:41:10 for a minute.

Comment: Be very aware that this only holds for ArrayList (if any List). Iterating into a LinkedList by index is quite expensive. (7) will only create a single temporary object and I really doubt that the difference is measurable. I most programs the time is spent doing something with each object in the list, not on the iteration mechanism itself...

Answer (score 7):

This list is a bit outdated, and shouldn't be really useful today.

It was a good reference some years ago, when Android devices were slow and had very limited resources. The Dalvik VM implementation also lacked a lot of optimizations available today.

On such devices, a simple garbage collection easily took **1 or 2 seconds** (for comparison, it takes around 20ms on most devices today). During the GC, the device just freezed, so the developers had to be very careful about memory consumption.

You shouldn't have to worry too much about that today, but if you really care about performance, here are some details :

```
(1) for (int i = initializer; i >= 0; i--) //hard to loop backwards
(2) int limit = calculate_limit(); for (int i=0; i < limit; i++)
(3) Type[] array = get_array(); for (Type obj : array)
```

These ones are easy to understand. `i >= 0` is faster to evaluate than `i < limit` because it doesn't read the value of a variable before doing the comparison. It works directly with an integer literal, which is faster.

I don't know why (3) should be slower than (2). The compiler should produce the same loop as (2), but maybe the Dalvik VM didn't optimize it correctly at this time.

```
(4) for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) //gets array.length everytime
(5) for (int i=0; i < this.var; i++) //has to calculate what this.var is
(6) for (int i=0; i < obj.size(); i++) //even worse calls function  each time
```

These ones are already explained in the comments.

```
(7) Iterable list = get_list(); for (Type obj : list)
```

`Iterables` are slow because they allocate memory, do some error handling, call multiple methods internally, ... All of this is much slower than (6) which does only a single function call on each iteration.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, any more details on why this is the case "Iterators allocate memory"? Thanks

Comment: I only know that it was a design choice to reduce the complexity of `Iterator.remove()` internally (and maybe speed it up).

Comment: Was reading this [java-temporary-iterators-are-slowing-my-android-game] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490240/java-temporary-iterators-are-slowing-my-android-game)

Answer (score 4):

I felt my first answer was not satisfactory and really didn't help to explain the question; I had posted the link to [this site](http://nothings.org/computer/iterate.html) and elaborated a bit, which covered some basic use cases, but not the nitty-gritty of the issue. So, I went ahead and did a little hands-on research instead.

I ran two separate codes:

```
    // Code 1
    int i = 0;
    Integer[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (Integer obj : array) {
        i += obj;
    }
    System.out.println(i);

    // Code 2
    int i = 0;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    for (Integer obj : list) {
        i += obj;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
```

Of course, both print out `15`, and both use an `Integer` array (no `int`s).

Next, I used `javap` to disassemble these and look at the bytecode. (I ignored the initialization; everything before the `for` loop is commented out.) Since those are quite lengthy, I posted them at PasteBin [here](http://pastebin.com/36anZkQT).

Now, while the bytecode for code 1 is actually *longer*, it is less intensive. It uses `invokevirtual` only once (aside from the `println`), and no other invocations are necessary. In code 1, it seems to optimize the iteration to a basic loop; checking the array length, and loading into our variable, then adding to `i`. This appears to be optimized to behave *exactly* as `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { ... }`.

Now, in code 2, the bytecode gets much more intensive. It has to make 2 `invokeinterface` calls (both to `Iterator`) in addition to every other call that is needed above. Additionally, code 2 has to call `checkcast` because it is a generic `Iterator` (which is not optimized, as I mentioned above). Now, despite the fact that there are less calls to `load` and `store` operations, these aforementioned calls involve a substantial amount more overhead.

As he says in the video, if you find yourself needing to do a *lot* of these, you may run into problems. Running one at the start of an `Activity`, for example, probably is not too big a deal. Just beware creating many of them, especially iterating in `onDraw`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the compiler optimizes (3) to this (this is the part where I'm guessing):

```
for (int i =0; i < array.length; ++i)
{
    Type obj = array[i];

}
```

And (7) can't be optimized, since the compiler doesn't know what kind of Iterable it is. Which means that it really has to create a `new Iterator` on the heap. Allocating memory is expensive. And every time you ask for the next object, it goes trough some calls.

To give a rough sketch of what is happens when (7) gets compiled (sure about this):

```
Iterable<Type> iterable = get_iterable();
Iterator<Type> it = iterable.iterator(); // new object on the heap
while (it.hasNext()) // method call, some pushing and popping to the stack
{
    Type obj = it.next(); // method call, again pushing and popping


}
```

Comment: JVM is a stack machine so why memory allocation is expensive? JVM should just move stack pointer forward.

Comment: JVM has a heap as well... Every `new` you use is created on the heap. Think about it: it would be impossible that all `new`s would be created on the stack.

Comment: Dalvik is register-based, rather than stack-based.

Comment: So it doesn't have a stack, but it has a heap.

Comment: Iterator<Type> it = iterable.iterator();  Why this goes on the heap? If so, it only allocates the iterator object once (rather than once for every item) if I understand correctly?

Comment: But JVM heap works very close to a stack, as I know. When there is no enough place in heap to put an object in the end of it, then JVM does not analyse RAM for some empty space that will be enough for object allocation. JVM just perform a GC. Then the GC collect dereferenced objects and move every survivor to the beginning of a memory segment. This is a simplified model, but it shows that Java heap looks pretty like stack (except GC process). So allocation process should work very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to marshall the objects into a "linked list" based Iterator, and then support an API, as opposed to a chunk of memory and a pointer (array)

Answer (score 0):

Third variant is faster then 7 because array is reified type and JVM should just assign a pointer to a correct value. But when you iterate over a collection , then compiler can perform additional casts because of erasure. Actually compiler insert this casts to generic code to determine some dirty hacks like using deprecated raw types as soon as possible.

**P.S.** This is just a guess. In fact, I think that the compiler and JIT compiler can perform any optimisation (JIT even in runtime) and result can depend on particular details like JVM version and vendor.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Android, this is the video from Google Developers in 2015.

**To Index or Iterate? (Android Performance Patterns Season 2 ep6)**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZOf3pOAM6A

They did the test on DALVIK runtime, 4.4.4 build, 10 times, to got average results.
The result shows "For index" is the best.

```js
int size = list.size();
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    Object object = list.get(index);
    ...
}
```

They also suggest to do similar test by yourself on your platform at the end of the video.